# How to create and drop database, schema PostgreSQL by Java code?

Tags: java, postgresql

I try

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import com.ibatis.common.jdbc.ScriptRunner;

public static void createDatabase() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/postgres", "postgres", "123456a@");
        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
        stmt.executeQuery("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS foo");
        stmt.executeQuery("USE foo");
        connection.close();
    }
```

and

```
public static void dropDatabase() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/", "postgres", "123456a@");
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    statement.executeUpdate("DROP DATABASE foo");
    connection.close();
}
```

but create, also drop method not success.

Error when call create method:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "NOT"
  Position: 20
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2453)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2153)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:286)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:432)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:358)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:305)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:291)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:269)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeQuery(PgStatement.java:236)
    at com.nttdata.RunSqlScript.createDatabase(RunSqlScript.java:57)
    at com.nttdata.RunSqlScript.main(RunSqlScript.java:27)
```

Error when call drop method:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: database "foo" is being accessed by other users
  Detail: There is 1 other session using the database.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2453)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2153)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:286)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:432)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:358)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:305)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:291)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:269)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeUpdate(PgStatement.java:249)
    at com.nttdata.RunSqlScript.dropDatabase(RunSqlScript.java:71)
    at com.nttdata.RunSqlScript.main(RunSqlScript.java:28)
```

Comment: Are you open to using liquibase or other utilities ?

Comment: I must manipulating PostgreSQL from Java, I willingness use 3th party tools

Comment: Where in the Postgres manual did you find the `USE` command or the `IF NOT EXISTS` for `DROP DATABASE`?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, the SQL syntax used while creating a database is incorrect in your question. The stack trace says it all about the incorrect syntax.

If you want to check whether the database exists or not, then you might have to do something like this in your Java code:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select datname from pg_database where datname like 'foo';");
```

not by the `IF NOT EXISTS` approach

Accessing this `rs` object will let you know whether the database exists or not. Then you can fire either your `CREATE` or `DELETE` database operations accordingly.

```
String databaseName = "";
if(rs.next()) {
    databaseName = rs.getString("datname");
}
stmt.executeQuery("DROP DATABASE " + databaseName);
```

If a direct `DROP DATABASE` doesn't work (which I had faced a lot many times), you might consider using the `dropdb` utility or by one of the following approaches.

**APPROACH-1**

Use the following query to prevent future connections to your database(s):

```
REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE foo FROM public;
```

You can then terminate all connections to this database except your own:

```
SELECT pid, pg_terminate_backend(pid) 
FROM pg_stat_activity 
WHERE datname = current_database() AND pid <> pg_backend_pid();
```

Since that you have revoked the CONNECT rights to the corresponding database, no external `auto-connect`'s will no longer be able to do so. You'll now be able to drop the database without any issues.

**APPROACH-2:**

This approach goes by the batch job way, where you can invoke this class from the corresponding jar:

```
Process batchProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin/psql -h \"DB SERVER ADDRESS\" -U postgres -f C:/batch.sql");
```

`batch.sql` holds the SQL DROP DATABASE statements, which will be dropped when executed.

Hope this helps!

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ResultSet not positioned properly, perhaps you need to call next.`

Comment: Obvious thing is to check whether the `ResultSet` contains anything or not using the `rs.next()`, updated the answer. Please check!

Comment: Use `Process` is nice idea.  `C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin/psql -h \"DB SERVER ADDRESS\" -U postgres -f C:/batch.sql` how to add password?

Comment: Aren't you able to DROP the database with a normal `DROP DATABASE` command. The approach of calling the utility directly goes by a batch job! It will prompt for password then!

Comment: Oh, no. It must run automatically.

Comment: @DoNhuVy, Updated my answer based on your question! Please check!

Comment: Thank friends for many helpful information. In your approach2, I must do everything automatically, therefore prompt password will make approach-2 failure.

Comment: There is no difference in dropping the database through JDBC or through the command line. In both cases you can only drop it if no connection is open to that database and you can't drop the database you are connected to

Comment: Understood @a_horse_with_no_name, I was clarifying the syntactical error that OP has in his question. Thank you for clarifying this to the rest of the world!

Comment: You wrote: "*If a direct DROP DATABASE doesn't work (which I had faced a lot many times), you might consider dropping using the command prompt, which is simple enough anyway*" - I was referring to that.

Comment: Yeah, with all respect to your comment there are situations where DROP DATABASE doesn't drop the database due to active connections to it right. I was suggesting the utility / batch job approach and OP wanted it to be automated.

Answer (score 1):

An option that you can try to use is to use a database migration tool like [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/). There are couple of options that you can try from liquibase. One is to have an executable directly executed from the code (You first create a database change log file , with change sets. One of the commands in the change sets will be an executable

```
<changeSet author="exec-change-drop" id="drop-foo">
    <executeCommand executable="<bat file with drop for PSQL or dropdb>"/>
</changeSet>
```

Another option that you can try is to write a sql and call it

```
<changeSet id="exec-change-drop2" author="drop-foo-2">  
   <sql>DROP DATABASE foo;</sql>  
</changeSet>
```

You can then execute this from your code as follows

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/postgres", "postgres", "123456a@");

Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(connection));

Liquibase liquibase = new liquibase.Liquibase("path/to/changelog.xml", new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), database);

liquibase.update(new Contexts(), new LabelExpression());
```

Note that your changeLogSchema may need to be in a different schema so that it executes seamlessly.

Additionally liquibase can be added with maven (this was the way it was supposed to be) and executed as well

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I hope have a chance to try your approach, then reply the answer.